Setting up Hive Server with 3-node Hadoop Cluster and MySQL on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
I have already configured a 3-node Hadoop cluster which is up and running on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS machines. I also have a MySQL server running on a different node but in the same zone. Now, I want to set up a single-node Hive server that can communicate with the 3-node Hadoop cluster and use MySQL for metadata information storage.
In all 3 Hadoop machines, I have Hadoop files located in /home/user/hadoopnode folder.
I am facing difficulties setting up Hive. I am using apache-hive-3.1.2-bin.
Here is my hive-site.xml configuration:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.uri</name>
        <value>thrift://192.XXX.XX.XX:9083</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
        <value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
        <value>jdbc:mysql://192.XXX.XX.XX:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
        <value>user</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
        <value>pass123</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.thrift.bind.host</name>
        <value>192.XXX.XX.XX</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
        <value>10000</value> 
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.sasl.enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
        <description>If true, the metastore Thrift interface will be secured with SASL. Clients must authenticate with Kerberos.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
        <value>NONE</value>
    </property>
</configuration>


And the content of hive-env.sh is:
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/user/hadoopnode
export HIVE_CONF_DIR=/home/user/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/conf

And the .bashrc file of the Hive server contains:
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

######################### HIVE #######################################
export HIVE_HOME=/home/user/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin
export HIVE_CONF_DIR=/home/user/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/conf
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin

When I try to run $HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool, I get the following error:
Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must be set or hadoop must be in the path

Can anyone with expertise in this regard help me out?

Check which hadoop and point $HADOOP_HOME to that location

how to do this ? Will this work ?
export HADOOP_HOME=192.168.XX.XXX:/home/user/hadoopnode/bin

In your file hive-env.sh change $HADOOP_HOME to export HADOOP_HOME=/home/user/hadoopnode/bin
